# Queens on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

What is the smallest number of queens that can be placed on a chessboard so that every square is either occupied or can be reached in one move?

Comment: see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

Comment: This problem is a bit different, to my understanding.

Comment: This might be it then: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html

Comment: Yup, that's it. However, this was during a math contest; is there any way to figure out the minimum number without external info/computers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest number is $5$:

[image]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/QueensMin_700.gif))</sub>

It was discussed on MathOverflow why $4$ won't suffice: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30330/is-there-a-good-argument-for-why-you-cant-place-4-queens-which-cover-a-chessboa

Apparently there's no known nice solution and exhaustive search is required.